# Leaflet: GeoJSON (via fetch url) does not display marker popup

Tags: leaflet, fetch, geojson

I am trying to display open radioactivity data from the German Agency for Protection of Radiation (https://www.imis.bfs.de/geoportal/).
They have a nice [GeoJson API](https://www.imis.bfs.de/ogc/opendata/ows?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=opendata:odlinfo_odl_1h_latest&outputFormat=application/json).

I can display the individual markers (points of radioactivity sensors), but cannot display the value `feature.properties.value` in a popup.

I tried `onEachFeature` but somehow it did not work. I searched for quite a bit, but could not find a solution

html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Radioaktivität</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

JavaScript:

```js
let config = {
  minZoom: 2,
  maxZoom: 18,
};

const zoom = 7;

const lat = 51.7036;
const lng = 10.2166;

const map = L.map("map", config).setView([lat, lng], zoom);

let url = 'https://www.imis.bfs.de/ogc/opendata/ows?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=opendata:odlinfo_odl_1h_latest&outputFormat=application/json';

const response = fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
    L.geoJson(response, {
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.value);
      }
    }).addTo(map);
  });
```

Comment: The parameter of `bindPopup` must be either a `HTMLElement` or a `String`. Make sure you're not passing `null`s or `Number`s. Cast types as needed.

Comment: @IvanSanchez is absolutly correct. I just tested this and the value property is a Float or NULL.  `layer.bindPopup(String(feature.properties.value));` should fix this.

Comment: @IvanSanchez & @b-raabe I thank you very much, it worked now. `layer.bindPopup(String(feature.properties.value));` solved the problem. And I learned that indeed `Number` cannot be passed.